# iPhone Add new non consumable product to existing released application

Tags: ios, in-app

In released app with non consumable In-App purchases.

Can i add new non consumable product for existing released iPhone application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you have to release an update to the app and go through the normal approval process. (I.e. you can't patch new in-app-purchases to an existing app without releasing a new version)